How to setup DB2 container in Linux VM using Podman (non-root) user
I've setup Podman using non-root user in CentOS 9 machine.
The user is added to docker group. I am able to run and setup containers in the env as well. But when trying to run and setup the db2server using below command:
podman run -d  -e DB2INSTANCE=test \
  --name db2_container \
  -e LICENSE=accept \
  -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=mypassword \
  -e DBNAME=testdb \
  -v database:/database \
  --privileged=true \
  -p 50002:50002 \
  docker.io/ibmcom/db2:11.5.7.0a

The container is failing to come up and following error is encountered.
No Cgroup memory limit detected, instance memory will follow automatic tuning
(*) Remounting /database with suid... 
mount: /database: permission denied.
(*) Nothing appears in the Db2 directory. will skip update/upgrade.
(*) Code level is the same. No update/upgrade needed.
And the db2 container is not coming up.

Podman version:
podman version 5.0.2
Already tried solutions:

Tried to disable SELinux, using --security-opt label=disable. This as well and it didn't work. I got the same error again.
Tried to do userns-id, that as well didn't work.

How can I successfully run db2 container using Podman (non-root) user in CentOS 9 machine?
P.S. The same works if I try using root user in the machine.

If you use --privileged=true then the Db2-instance wants to run as root.

Have tried removing the --privileged=true  as well but still its not working. Encountering the same error as above.

Ensure owner:group for the host location for container /database match the Db2-instance-owner of the container, and permissions 755 at least on that path on host.

The database folder on the host gets created as part of the above run in path podman /.local/share/containers/storage/volumes/database.
Also, The above mount is failing If I try to run it inside the container with the root user:
drwxr-xr-x    6 root   root        58 Nov 20 07:21 database
drwxr-xr-x    1 root   root       102 Nov 20 07:21 run
dr-xr-x---    1 root   root        27 Nov 20 07:34 root
drwxrwxrwt    1 root   root      4096 Nov 21 10:08 tmp
[root@ef86a94a6912 /]# mount -o remount,suid /database
mount: /database: permission denied.
